# What is the Covariant Differentation?

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry

What is the Covariant Differentation? and what is the difference with Covariant Derivative?
Unfortunately I didn't find anything on the web

Thank you

Comment: Maybe this article will help you:
https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Covariant_differentiation

Comment: By "what is the difference with Covariant Derivative?", do you mean "What is the difference between covariant derivative and regular derivative?", or something else? Also, I personally enjoyed [this series of video lectures](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlXfTHzgMRULkodlIEqfgTS-H1AY_bNtq) on the subject, they might teach you something as well.

Comment: @Arthur: I mean the difference between Covariant Differentation and Covariant Derivative

Comment: Differentiation is the act of taking a derivative, no matter what kind of derivative it is.

Comment: @Richard: Thank you, now I read the article

Comment: The difference is this (at least in my head): You use the covariant derivative when performing covariant differentiation. Also, the result of a covariant differentiation is a covariant derivative. So one word describes the process, while the other describes the tool and the result.